# web3.js: How to get password from private key?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

I want to make transaction using web3.js but I am not understanding from where I get password to unlock account .

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('account address ', " password", duration);
```

Answer (score 3):

`password` is the password you used when creating the account, and is required to decrypt  your private key.

There is no way to derive your password *from* the private key or keyfile: that's not how it works.

If you've forgotten your password, then either create a new account with a new password (which you remember), or look at one of the brute-force-based password recovery tools.